# Intel x86_64 assembly function calling conventions(linux, windows), stack arguments, stack manipulation

Tags: nasm, x86-64, intel, masm, calling-convention

I call assembly function from C (separate asm file), and pass 6 pointer arguments to it.

In Linux(using Nasm) calling convention is : rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9 and rest on stack.
In Windows (using Masm) calling convention is: rcx, rdx, r8, r9 and rest on stack.

How can I address that rest on stack arguments on both platforms??
I read 64 abi and microsoft msdn but I can't see clear answer how to use this arguments, all my tries ended up with segmentation fault.

Another question is : is it necessary in MASM to do this :

```
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
```

at my assembly function beginning?(and of course reverse it at the end).

Comment: 1. look at compiler output to see how the compiler does it.  You're obviously doing something wrong, but you didn't post any code.  The best answer I can give based on that is "do it the normal way"...   Single-step your code in a debugger, and note where the args on the stack were pushed, and make sure that's the same address you try to load from.  You probably forgot that `push` changes `rsp` or that `call` pushes a return address, and have the wrong offset from `rsp` (or `rbp`)

Comment: 2. AFAIK, no, making a stack frame isn't necessary for Windows code.  It's definitely not for code that will run under Linux, but [Windows has SEH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx).  If you don't make a stack frame with `rbp`, it may be necessary to use assembler directives to generate metadata to allow stack-unwinding for exception-handling (even if your function is a leaf function).  Necessary for safe use, I mean; working once doesn't prove it's safe.  I haven't looked at asm for Windows, so I won't post that as an answer.

Comment: According to compiler output, isn't true, that addressing on stack before function call differs with the one after call??

Comment: In general, you just read the values directly from the stack (similar to the way you would load/store local variables).  There is one [trick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) to be aware of: *The caller is responsible for allocating space for parameters to the callee, and must always allocate sufficient space for the 4 register parameters, even if the callee doesn’t have that many parameters.* So when you go to the stack for the 'other' values, make sure you skip over the ones already in registers.